# how can i count monthly orders by using SQL and Month function?

Tags: sql, asp.net

i need to calculate how many orders were processed during the year however i have a field named datePrepped in which i have the date so that i am using the function Month() to get the month i need to have this for all the months of the years

i don t want to group i need the output to be stored in a variables that is why i am using AS Jan AS Feb etc. however i am getting this error [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1.

```
    sqlString = "SELECT " & _
   "SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped)='1', 1, 0)) AS Jan," & _
   "SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped)='2', 0)) AS Feb," & _
   "SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped)='3', 0)) AS Mar," & _
   "SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped)='4', 0)) AS Apr," & _
   "SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped)='5', 0)) AS May " & _
   "FROM OrderControl AS r;"
```

Example of output needed

```
   <%=MyRecordset("Jan")%> HTML output 500
    <%=MyRecordset("Feb")%> HTML output 800
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `'1'`s in most of the `iif()` expressions:

```
SELECT SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped) = 1, 1, 0)) AS Jan,
       SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped) = 2, 1, 0)) AS Feb,
       SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped) = 3, 1, 0)) AS Mar,
       SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped) = 4, 1, 0)) AS Apr,
       SUM(IIf(Month(r.datePrpped) = 5, 1, 0)) AS May
FROM OrderControl AS r;
```

The `MONTH()` function returns a number so it is appropriate that the comparison value be a number, not a string.